# Table Row Sum Within PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php

I want to sum table rows dynamically as the user inputs values. Since the number of rows can vary I want to use a php loop to accomplish this. I'm having problems getting the loop to work correctly. If, for example, there are two individual rows to sum only the bottom row will be summed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sumScoreF = function(a) { 
    var rowtotal = 0;
    n = new Array();

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) { 
       if (parseInt(document.getElementById(a + i).value) > 0) {
           n[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById(a + i).value);
           rowtotal += n[i];
       }
     }

     document.getElementById(a + 'total').value = rowtotal;
};
</script>
```

The following is an example of a single row sum. The total column continues to be summed as values are entered. This is a nice effect but not necessary.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
    <td>total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="p1g1" id="p1g1" type="text" value="" onChange="sumScoreF('p1g')" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="p1g2" id="p1g2" type="text" value="" onChange="sumScoreF('p1g')" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="p1g3" id="p1g3" type="text" value="" onChange="sumScoreF('p1g')" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name="p1gtotal" id="p1gtotal" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my attempt at looping additional rows using php and javascript. The first row will not sum but the second row will. I think the problem is with the javascript variable "m" in that it goes directly to the last row but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
    <td>total</td>
</tr>
<?php for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var k = <?php echo json_encode($j); ?>;
  var m = 'p'+k+'g';
</script>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g1'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g1'; ?>" type="text" onChange="sumScoreF('m')" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g2'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g2'; ?>" type="text" onChange="sumScoreF('m')" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g3'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g3'; ?>" type="text" onChange="sumScoreF('m')" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'gtotal'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'gtotal'; ?>" type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty horrible way to do it, but you are overwriting the `m` variable each time you loop in PHP, try appending `$j` to all instances of that variable as well. Otherwise your DOM bound `onChange` calls don't target the correct variables you want to pass into the `sumScore` function

Comment: If you want to add `<tr>`s on user input you will probably have to use AJAX, unless you don't need the extra rows information in a database, then you can just use JavaScript.

Comment: Thank-you @scrowler. Overwriting the m variable for each iteration of the loop was intended. When j is 1, m is p1g and p1gtotal should (I thought!) display the sum of row 1. When I enter a value in row 1 column 1, p2gtotal displays a zero immediately in row 2 column total, row 1 column total doesn't display anything, when I enter a value in row 2, row 2 starts to add up correctly. It looks like the m variable is going straight to p2g and waiting for p2g values and p1g is somehow negated. I checked that m is changing properly in the loop.

Comment: @MikeH Answer your own question, so it will be useful to future users of this site.  Otherwise, your question shows up as unanswered.

Comment: The answer code works perfectly in my PHP script. The problem was trying to modify the javascript variable 'm' in the PHP loop using javascript. This caused 'm' to go to the last value in the loop on page load. I removed the javascript code and modified the onChange function call. I now echo the PHP loop variable within the function call. Took a few tries to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used PHP to echo the loop variable within the onChange javascript function call:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
    <td>total</td>
    </tr>
    <?php for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g1'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g1'; ?>" type="text" onChange="sumScoreF('<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g'; ?>')" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g2'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g2'; ?>" type="text" onChange="sumScoreF('<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g'; ?>')" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g3'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g3'; ?>" type="text" onChange="sumScoreF('<?php echo 'p'.$j.'g'; ?>')" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'gtotal'; ?>" id="<?php echo 'p'.$j.'gtotal'; ?>" type="text" />
  </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```